# Express a irreducible polynomial $f(X)$ in the field of characteristic $p>0$ $F[X]$ as $g(X^{p^m})$

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

$F[X]$ is of the form $a_0+a_1X+...+a_nX^n$ where $a_0,a_1,...a_n\in F\text{ with characteristic p>0}.$
Express $f\in F[X]\ as\ g(X^{p^m})$, where the nonnegative integer m is a large as possible and $f$ is irreducible. Show that g is irreducible and separable.

This is a problem in section 3.4 of ***Basic Algebra*** by Robert Ash.

The question I had about is how to write $f(X)$ in form of $g(X^{p^m})$. I have tried this using the property $(a+b)^p=a^p+b^p$, since $F$ has characteristic p and the Frobenius Automorphism indicate if $\alpha \in F, \alpha = \beta ^p,$ for some $\beta \in F$. $g(X^{p^m})$ can be therefore written as $(b_0+b_1X+...+b_nX^n)^{p^m}.$ This is writing $g(X^{p^m})$ in in form of $f(X)$, for the other way around, is it just taking the $p^m$ root of the above expression:
$$f(X)=\sqrt[p^m]{g(X^{p^m})}$$

Comment: As you state this it is not true: for $p=2$, $f=X^4$, $g=X^2$ we have $f(X)=g(X^2)$ but $g$ is not irreducible. Perhaps you can type the question exactly it is in Ash?

Comment: Thank you for reminding, I will change the question.

Comment: But it is still false. Take $f=X(X+1)$, then we must have $g=f$ (with $m=0$) and $g$ is not irreducible. There must be more to the question than this. Is $f$ just possibly meant to be the minimal polynomial of some element in an extension field?

Comment: I add the condition $f$ is irreducible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that $g$ is irreducible follows from the fact that $f$ is; i.e. if $g = h_1 h_2$ then $f = h_1(x^{p^m})h_2(x^{p^m})$.

Once we show existence, this proves that $g$ is separable too: an irreducible polynomial is separable iff $g' \neq 0$, and in characteristic $p$ the fact that $g' = 0$ in turn means that $g = \widetilde{g}(x^p)$ for some $\widetilde g$. We cannot have the latter, otherwise it would contradict the maximality of $m$.

Now, consider

$S = \{m \in \mathbb N_0 : f = g(x^{p^m}), \text{ for some $g$}\}.$

The set $S$ is non empty, because $0 \in S$, and it is bounded above by degree considerations. Hence there exists $m = \max S$ with an associated $g$, which is irreducible and separable by the previous remarks.

Comment: You mean inseparable iff g’=0?

Comment: Yes, my bad. Fixed now!